# Can I Use the Microsoft Graph API to get the id of folder within a sharepoint document library?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to use the microsoft graph api to get the id of a folder within a sharepoint document library? If so, how?

I can see in the documentation that I can get the path of a folder and/or file, and make queries based on this path. But what I would like is to get an id, so if the folder and/or file ever changes name, I can still query that specific folder and/or file. Is this possible?

Specifically, I am creating an internal dashboard for my employees. We have a Folder in a sharepoint document library called "Contacts". Within this "Contacts" folder we have n number of subfolders such as "John Doe," "Jane Doe," etc. If an employee is viewing the information for John Doe within our internal employee dashboard, I'd like to display the any child folders and/or files of John Doe.

Again, all I can find in the graph api documentation is how to query based on the relative path. I'd like to be able to use the API to get an id for any folder and/or file, as well as to return any child objects of any folder using the id (and not the relative path). How can I do this?

Comment: Yes you can get the id of a folder using the below call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteid/drives/{document libraryid}/root/children`. This will give you all the files and folders in your document library. If you are looking for the document library id you can use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteid/drives`. This gives you the document library id

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity That first api call you share will give me all files and folders in a document library. But once I know the id of a specific folder, is there a way to retrieve a list of child folders and files within that specific folder and only have it return results one level deep? For example, let's say that in root I have Folder1, Folder2, Folder3. And let's say Folder1 contains the children SubfolderA and FileX. And let's say SubfolderA contains the children FileQ and FileW. I'd like the query using the id for Folder1 and retrieve just SubfolderA and FileX. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You should use the below query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drives/{document libraryid}/items/{folderid}/children`. If you want to get the folder id use this call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drives/{document libraryid}/root/children` and get the id of the folder :)-

Comment: Moving this to Answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You should use the below query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drives/{document libraryid}/items/{folderid}/children.
```

If you want to get the folder id use this call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drives/{document libraryid}/root/children and get the id of the folder
```